# UITableViewCell automatic height incorrect on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

We all came across a `UITableView` where we wanted to have different cell heights that adopt dynamically to font sizes. Now in my table view I have multiple different cells that have a different height. 
I used the standard code to allow estimated heights and dynamic resizing:

```swift
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 450.0
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Now my new cell has been created using a `xib` file so I can check if all constraints have been set correctly. The weird thing is that when I run it on the iOS Simulator the cell height is rendered too small.

It does not matter what constraint I use even when I preset a height constraint the height of the cell will always be around the same height as the other cells, which use a correct automatic height. 
When I want to debug this issue by using the View Debugger in Xcode the height of cell will be rendered correctly as I wanted it.

Here's a screenshot as an example: 
[image]

The left side shows the view debugger. The right size the iOS simulator. 
The same thing happens if I use an App like Reveal.

Maybe someone had the same issue and can help me with it.

Comment: I don't think this is issue of **UITableViewAutomaticDimension**, I think its your constraint/anchor problem. Show your all constraint of this page of anchor.

Comment: This is definitely a constraint problem. The image in the cell on the right is taller than the one on the left. Please post the necessary details for us to debug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet your `UIImageView` doesn't clip image  :)

**just set**

```
yourImageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

and it should help

Comment: Absolutely correct! I was searching in the complete wrong direction and did not see the obvious solution.